# k-th power of all roots of unity over $\mathbb{K}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, roots-of-unity

Let $n \geq 2$ and let $\omega_1,...\omega_n$ be all the $n$th roots of unity, not necessarily distinct over an arbitrary field $\mathbb{K}$. Prove that

$\omega_1 ^k + \omega_2^k+...+\omega_n^k = n$,  if  $k = 0$ and

$\omega_1 ^k + \omega_2^k+...+\omega_n^k= 0$, if $k = 1,...,n-1$

I think I should somehow make use of the the fact that

$1+ \omega + \omega^2+...+\omega^{n-1} = 0$, if $\omega\neq1$ and

$1+ \omega + \omega^2+...+\omega^{n-1} = n$, if $\omega=1$

But I don't see how I can use it since we have power $k$. Can anyone give me a hint? thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "not necessarily distinct"? Clearly $1+1\neq 0$ over $\mathbb{R}$ for $n=2$.

Comment: Is the first statement not trivial?  $\omega_j^0=1, \, \forall j$, no?

Comment: Are you sure this field can be arbitrary? Shouldn't we require characteristic 0 at least?

Comment: @freakish i understand it this way that some of the $\omega$ might be the same. but the field does not necessarily be $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @mjw I am not sure. I am thinking what if $\mathbb{K}$ is a finite field, then I still need to show that the sum is $n$

Comment: @Livpez. This is false as it is. Consider $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $n=3$ (or any odd $n$). There is a single root $1$ and $1^k+1^k+1^k=1\neq 0$ regardless of $k$.

Answer (score 1):

$$w_k=e^{2i\pi k/n},$$ then use the summation of a G.P to get $$S=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} w^k_j=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} e^{2i\pi jk/n}= \frac{ e^{2i \pi k}-1}{e^{2i\pi k/n}-1}=0, ~if~k\ne pn, p \in I$$
If $k=pn$, then $$S=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} e^{2i\pi j p}=n,$$
as $e^{2i \pi j p}=1.$

Comment: thanks for your help. but unfortunately I need to prove this for any arbitrary field. not necessarily over $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Shouldn't your sum go from $j=0$ to $j=n-1$?

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I have corrected it now.