Prove that sum of rotating complex exponential equals $0$
I want to show that, with $n$ a positive number, $k$ a nonzero integer and $-(n-1) \leq k \leq n-1$
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} e^{i2\pi kj/n} = 0$$
With $k = 1$, I can intuitively understand the statement is true, since the complex vector forms an $n$-sided regular polygon. But with $k$ being other numbers I don't have an intuition that convinces me. I would like to find a proof but can't figure out how. Is there any method to prove this using simple complex analysis?

looks like a geometric series

Ooof thanks. You are right. I should have thought of that.

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3865747/42969

If you think of this series as generating a walk in the complex plane, it seems you trace out (a subset of) the vertices of a regular $n$-gon. That suggests that the intuition should boil down to: if you repeatedly add $k$ to itself mod $n$, then eventually you reach zero.

Let $x=e^{i2\pi k/n}$.  Given the constraints on $k$, $x^n=1$ but $x\ne1$, so,
using the formula for the sum of a geometric series, the sum is $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}x^j=\dfrac{x^n-1}{x-1}=0.$

Letting $\sum=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1} e^{i2\pi kj/n}$ and  $r=e^{i2\pi k/n}$
$r\sum=\sum$
i.e. $(r-1)\sum=0$
If $0<|k|<n$ then $r\neq 1$ hence $\sum=0$
You can replace the condition $k$ nonzero and $-(n-1) \leq k \leq n-1$ by just $n∤k$. (If $n=1$ there's no possible $k$ either way and your statement is vacuously true.)

Why $r\sum =\sum?$

The  summands are cycled when multiplied by $r$. Term for j=n is 1 as is the term for j=0, the rest move up one.

@calc ll - previous comment in response to your query. (Forgot to address it.)

Alternate way of looking at it: we get $(n,k)$ geometric series of length $n/(n,k).$   Each of those is the sum of the $n/(n,k)$-th roots of unity,  hence zero.
The reason is that if $\zeta $ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity,  then $\zeta^k$ is a primitive $n/(n,k)$-th root of unity,  by this.
